# Has a pad abort ever been done on an actual launch?

Tags: launch, abort, launch-escape-system, tractor-les

In light of the recent SpaceX Dragon test, I was wondering if any pad aborts have ever been performed during an actual launch? To my limited knowledge, none have occurred, despite the Soyuz and Apollo vehicles having the capability.

The only launch accident I know of is the Challenger disaster, which could not be saved with the abort modes available to the Shuttle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Soyuz 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-ST_No._16L) used the launch escape tower from the pad.

Comment: Good grief, they didn't even give abort control to the crew -- abort had to be triggered from the ground.

Comment: Ask it as a full question.  That is a much more complex answer.  Basically there are several levels of abort. Some MUST be automated, since humans cannot respond in time.  Then you hit the Mercury-Redstone 4 where either the door misfired, or Gus Grissom incorrectly blew it off.  Risk there is it is possible to abort.

Comment: I'm not asking a question, just commenting on the Soviet tendency to give the crew as little control as feasible, even to the extent of not giving them the ability to trigger abort. Spam in a can.

Comment: 14 to 17 G's!  The crew survived, but required the immediate administration of vodka after landing.  I would too.

Comment: @MarkAdler Very curious to hear what the G numbers were for SpaceX then.

Comment: About four G's.

Comment: 4g average, Musk said it peaked at 6g: https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/596053122587365376

Comment: @RussellBorogove: From the article, it sounded like the crew did have control... until their wires burned through. Then they had a second level of control on the ground as fallback, that was what ultimately triggered it.

Comment: From the article: "The **launch control team** activated the escape system but the control cables had already burned through, and the Soyuz crew could not activate or control the escape system themselves."

Comment: Supposed video of the Soyuz 10 abort: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyFF4cpMVag

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to define 'pad abort' as you are talking about both Apollo, Soyuz and the Space Shuttle. Apollo/Soyuz and Space Shuttle are vastly different vehicles, hence they have vastly different definitions of aborts.

There were five [RSLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_abort_modes#Redundant_Set_Launch_Sequencer_.28RSLS.29_abort) (Redundant Set Launch Sequencer) [aborts during the STS programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_abort_modes#Space_Shuttle_abort_history) (on STS-41-D, STS-51, STS-51-F, STS-55 and STS-68). Since these occur after main engine start but before booster ignition (after which the shuttle was committed to launch) I would technically qualify these as 'pad aborts', albeit a lot less spectacular than pad aborts for Apollo or Soyuz.

Comment: I read the question as meaning "rapidly departing the pad" not, aborting and going home for the evening.

Comment: This probably dates me, but don't forget Gemini-6A http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_6A

Comment: @User58220 Yes. That immediately came to mind :-). I was 14 fwiw.